# Proper way to wait for List<CompletableFuture<Void>> to indicate all operations have finished

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, java-15

I am running several hundred functions with runAsync(). All of the functions modify some statically available list and thus do not need to return anything. I want to make sure they all finish before continuing my processing. Is this the appropriate way to wait? Is there a simpler way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
active_sites.forEach(site -> site.getEntryPoints().stream().map(EntryPoint::scanEntryPoint).forEach(futures::add));
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify that quite a bit:

```java
CompletableFuture[] scans = active_sites.stream()
    .flatMap(site -> site.getEntryPoints().stream())
    .map(EntryPoint::scanEntryPoint)
    .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
CompletableFuture.allOf(scans).join();
```

Comment: That is a good deal simpler. Could I get rid of the local variable too? Perhaps something like: `CompletableFuture.allOf(active_sites.stream().flatMap(site -> site.getEntryPoints().stream()).map(EntryPoint::scanEntryPoint).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();`

Comment: Sure, but I think that hurts readability. (Just like your relatively long lambda in `active_sites.forEach`, by the way.)